# Problemas pasando Laravel a producción

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un vhost con Windows Server (servidor de producción) donde tengo instalado ambiente Xampp. Quiero subir mi primer proyecto en Laravel, lo deje en la carpeta htdocs he ingreso por la url(sistemas/miproyecto/public), me toma la página de login muy bien pero al querer validar los datos de usuario y contraseña me da el error

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Depuré y puse un `dd()` en el `route/web.php` pero no entra la función del controlador

No he configurado ningún archivo y solo apunté la base de datos a la que corresponde.

Comment: ¿XAMPP en producción?

Comment: si, es un windows server con xampp que utilizo como servidor de producción para trabajos personales

Comment: creaste un virtual host que apunte a la carpeta /public de tu proyecto?

Comment: si, pero por alguna razón me lo toma la config

Comment: si configuraste un virtual host, no dedberias entrar en la direccion a /public, puedes poner la configuracion que hayas hecho y en que archivos para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: revisa el archivo **.env**.  Estás usando el helper `url()`por lo que si no esta bien la url en este archivo ahí puede llegar a estar el problema. Acordate que si lo modificás tenés que reiniciar el servicio para que tome los cambios.